# Exclude namespace or assembly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

Im using Unity and get problem with one of our 3rd party controls.
Can i exclude a namespace, so Microsoft Unity not include this?

This is the error message

> [ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type
>   = "DevExpress.Web.Internal.TabItemSpacerControlLite", name = "(none)"

Comment: How are you registering the classes?

Comment: I have not registred any classes yet..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. One of the third party control had two constructors who took one parameter. I had to specify which one to use.

```
private static void RegisterDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // TODO: Add any dependencies needed here
    container
        .RegisterType(typeof(TabItemSpacerControlLite), typeof(TabItemSpacerControlLite), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(TabBase)));
}
```